# The method andProperty(String) from the type QueryBuilder is deprecated - Javers

Tags: java, javers

I am developing `Spring Boot Javers integrations` from link: https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/, andProperty API has been deprecated, what's the replacement for this ?

```
@GetMapping("/audit")
    public String getPersonChanges(@RequestParam Optional<String> param) {
        QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(Person.class);
        jqlQuery = param.isPresent() ? jqlQuery.andProperty(param.get()) : jqlQuery;

        List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());

        changes.sort((o1, o2) -> -1 * o1.getCommitMetadata().get().getCommitDate().compareTo(o2.getCommitMetadata().get().getCommitDate()));

        JsonConverter jsonConverter = javers.getJsonConverter();

        return jsonConverter.toJson(changes);
    }
```

> The method andProperty(String) from the type QueryBuilder is deprecated

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about replacement for this method is given explicitly in its javadoc:

```java
    /**
     * renamed to {@link #withChangedProperty(String)}
     * @deprecated
     */
    @Deprecated
    public QueryBuilder andProperty(String propertyName) {
        return withChangedProperty(propertyName);
    }
```